# Samsung top load washer WA54M8750AV/A4 Leak only during spin cycle

Tags: washer, samsung

My top load washer is leaking only during the spun cycle in the front right corner and only about 1/4 cup of water.

I've taken the back and top off and don't see any loose hoses, no cracked pump, top ring looks fine Any ideas?

Comment: A photo might help

Answer (score 0):

You are probably "flinging" water out the top of the spinning bucket. Two ounces is a small amount so it wouldn't be a hose or pump leak. Try a little smaller load.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I also though it might be something like that but even on small loads it does this and why now after 4 years?  Strange.

Comment: @PaulHuwa  Have you tried running it with the top off?  It might give you a clue as to what's going on. Other than being scarey, it should work... mine does.

Comment: No I havent tried that but I did thing about it.  Glad to see Im not alone with crazy ideas. lol

Comment: @PaulHuwa  That's how we all learned before the internet and sites like this .. lol

Answer (score 0):

Could be a leaking hose . That is what was wrong with ours. I bought an LG because service was difficult to get for Samsung.